# Should I use arm7 or arm64 in info.plist when publishing to Apple App Store (iOS/iPad)

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode has set arm7 as default when I started the project, but if I can recall, it should be arm64? Or do I remember wrong?

(info.plist > Required device capabilities > Item 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I have understood, armv7 is only relevant to filter out some 32 bit devices if you want your app to support the older Apple devices. From iOS 11, only 64bits applications are allowed to be installed from the Apple App Store, so if you do not target any earlier iOS versions, its safe to put the *Item 0* on arm64.